# S-Axis Shift Of Laplace Transform $f(t) = e^{-4t}t^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace transform for
>   $$f(t) = e^{-4t}t^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

**My Work So Far**

The form of $f(t)$ suggests that I should use an s-axis shift, $L${$t^{3/2}$} = $F(s+4)$.

I *think* that the appropriate form for this would then be $f(t) = t^a$, which according to my table should lead to $F(s) = \frac{Γ(\frac{5}{2})}{(s+4)^{5/2}}$.

The denominator is left as is, and the numerator is equivalent to $\int_o^∞e^{-t}t^{3/2}dt$.

This is an integration by parts, where:

$u=e^{-t}$, $du = -e^{-t}dt$, $dv = t^{3/2}$, and $v = \frac{2}{5}t^{5/2}$

Resulting in an equation to solve:

$$\lim_{T\to ∞}\frac{2e^{-t}t^{5/2}}{5}|_0^T+ \frac{2}{5}\int t^{5/2}e^{-t}dt$$

Except...wait. The remaining integral *also* requires integration by parts. And that will leave behind an integral that will *also* require an integration by parts. And so on. This means that I've clearly messed up because I've come up with a step that I can't escape from, but I don't know where that would have been. Would anyone be able to help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-t(s + 4)} t^{3/2} \, dt & = \frac{1}{(s+4)^{5/2}} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{3/2} \, du \\
& = \frac{1}{(s+4)^{5/2}} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{5/2-1} du \\
& = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{(s+4)^{5/2}}
\end{align}